Blazor IDE Errors
I created a file called Component.razor that had an identical @page as another file.  I deleted Component.razor but was still getting the below error.  I rebuild the Project but the error persisted.  I cleared the Chrome cache CTRL+F5 but the error persisted.  I was able to resolve the error by modify @page but I am curious what was happening here.
I am experiencing a lot of these kind of issues learning Blazor and I am finding the Visual Studio IDE sometimes inconsistent in it's behavior.


This isn't a problem with Visual Studio directly. Blazor comes with some code generation tasks that VS (and Rider) run in the background but seem to get out of sync when you rename/delete components. I would try cleaning the project/solution and rebuilding.

Thank you Phuzi.  I wasn't aware you could Clean the Solution.  Just started learning C# and Blazor.  I appreciate your response.

phuzi if you have time can you check out my other two unanswered posts? They are also related to Blazor / VS IDE type issues.  Copying and Pasting a file & Scaffolding.   Note:  I just tried copying and pasting a file in a new Project and it worked there.   This would suggest that my current project is possibly corrupted somehow.  Are there any further steps I can take other than Clean and Rebuild?  Thank you phuzi.

Your webapp is having trouble picking the right page as multiple page matches the requested URL.Check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0
and try to remove any irrelevant routes left in your project.
